# Unity 2d тени перекрывают друг друга

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, 2d

Всем привет! Наверняка кто то сталкивался или проходил мой путь) Делаю свою игру и уперся в тени , а именно в их перекрытие друг другом указал на прикрепленном фото. Вожусь третий день и не понимаю как это эффективно можно решить. Я думаю надо как то скриптом получить часть спрайта входящего в колиззию с другим и делать его полностью прозрачным , но моих знаний не хватает понять как получить эту площадь этого самого спрайта. Возможно этому есть решение более изящное но я пока не могу его найти и буду рад любому совету. Сами тени я сделал сдублировав объекты и сделал их прозрачность , затем заанимировал в аниматоре.
Прикладываю фото
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Напишу очевидные вещи, но это не тени, это спрайты, которые ведут себя как нормальные спрайты и ничего другого вы от них не получите. Это возможно, но решение вообще в области шейдеров.

Comment: А могли бы подсказать алгоритм действи? Не написать сам шейдер , а подсказать как правильно сделать. Так понял надо прикрутить к спрайтам шейдер который бы отбрасывал тень?

Comment: Стоит рисовать "тени" в отдельную текстуру со 100% непрозрачностью, затем уже эту готовую текстуру рисовать на экран с заданной прозрачностью. Потом можно будет еще добавить для нее размытие, наложение на фоновый мешь или еще какие-нибудь эффекты.